# Text after more tag in posts

Tags: posts, read-more

Hey,
is it possible that i can put a chunk of code somewhere and it will show up after the more tag seperator but within the post ?

I mean if i put more seperator after first paragraph then on post areas after that will show up the code i will put.. probably some html with a twitter and rss link.

Help is appreicated :) 
cheers
Ayaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will add your code after the `more` tag area on the post page:

```php
add_filter('the_content', 'adds_block');

function adds_block($content) {
    if (is_single()) {
        // return $content;
        global $post;
        $thePostID = $post->ID;
        $test = '<span id="more-' .$thePostID.'"></span>';
        return str_replace($test, ads(), $content);
    }
}

function ads(){
    return 'Your Custom Code,,';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the_tags hook to add your code to the tags output like this:

```
function add_my_code_after_tags($tags){
  $my_code =$tags . "your output here";
  return $my_code;
}

add_filter('the_tags','add_my_code_after_tags');
```

Comment: will it work after more  tag placement within the post ? single.php ...

Answer (score 0):

A filter on `the_content_more_link` may be appropriate for you, the filter should give you full control over the more link, so you could essentially add to it, remove it, or pre/ap-pend some extra content.

Here's an example, uncomment the appropriate line to prepend or append(ie. place extra content before or after the link).

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'custom_more_link', 1000 );

function custom_more_link( $more_link ) {

    $extra_more = '<br />My more link extra content';

    // Uncomment line below to prepend content
    //return $extra_more . $more_link;

    // Uncomment line below to append content
    //return $more_link . $extra_more;
}
```

**NOTE:** The extra content must be stored inside the variable returned.

Further reading/examples.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More
http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/07/01/how-to-filter-a-wordpress-themes-more-link-text

Hope that helps.. :)

Comment: but in this case wudn't it show on homepage or other pages which have more button available right ?, i wanted to make the area visible with in the post (single.php)

Comment: It should work on the home page(if your theme calls the_content and not the_excerpt), but naturally not on a single post page(the more link is not shown there).

Comment: in my question i mentioned to work within the post page

Comment: That's not how it reads, but i'll take your word on it being what you meant.. ;) Then really what you need is a shortcode that inserts the button in the relevant place, i'd suggest a read of the following: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/02/mastering-wordpress-shortcodes/

Comment: sorry my bad english , its not what i ws looking for becuase everything i would have to include a shortcode after more tag in the post editor, but it can do that work. So its not possible to just work on some function which will automatically put some text/code after the more tag in the post page ?

Comment: You want to add additional content when the more-tag is inserted in the editor?

Comment: yes , k here is the main picture, like for example i put more tag after 1st or 2nd paragraph, automatically it will insert link to my twitter and rss feed.. after that paragraph / area where <!--more--> was added in the editor in single.php/post page. i hope i make my self clear.

Comment: Ok, i think i follow, but you should understand the more link is not present on single post pages(when you view them), and additionally if you're inserting content into the editor, the user posting could simply delete the link from the editor.

Comment: The more-link functionality is provided by a TinyMCE plugin that's included with WordPress(a WordPress TinyMCE plugin), if you want to change that you'll need to acquaint yourself with writing TinyMCE plugins as that's currently beyond my own abilities(i'm not too hot with JS). For reference, the file in question is `wp-includes\js\tinymce\plugins\wordpress\editor_plugin.dev.js`..(you could modify it directly of course, just bear in mind you'll lose that with each update).

Comment: ohhh,, hmm k i will take a look , thx for the help :)